# Open source Swing GUI builder that uses MiGlayout

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, miglayout

Is there an open source Java swing GUI builder that uses MiGlayout as it's layout manager?  I've been trying to learn to make Swing GUI's by hand using MiGlayout but feel it would be easier to learn if the code is auto-generated.
**Note:** I'm not using the GUI builder for my applications, just to see how the code is generated and then applying (what I learned) and optimizing that code in my Java applications.  So I'm not specifically looking for IDE dependent Swing GUI builders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tried it, but it looks like you can add [`MiGLayout`](http://www.miglayout.com/) to the [`NetBeans`](http://netbeans.org/) GUI builder. The article [*Registering MigLayout in NetBeans*](http://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/registering_miglayout_in_netbeans_ide), which refers to this [project](http://kenai.com/projects/nbmiglayout/), now [archived](https://archive.org/details/kenai-com-2017-project-nbmiglayout), shows how. The generated code should be visible in a code fold.

Comment: I tried it, it has no support for any constraints. Just the plant horizontal alignment.

Comment: I'm surprised; I use the GUI editor to explore some of the more obscure layout parameters, e.g. `GridBagLayout`, or to prototype others, e.g. `GroupLayout`.

Comment: That project is not to be found.  It was on Kenai which is not defunct.  This question is not longer _answered_ I guess.